# Google OAuth2.0 error while authenticating, while being deployed on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have created an application which accesses sheets api using django. I am successfully able to authenticate using OAuth2.0, locally. But when I deployed my django code onto heroku, i am unable to authenticate. I am getting this

> can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: When you run the app does it load a home page? After you run the application do you load any type of Database connection? Are you loading any type of data from the Database after the authentication, or in between the authentication? Does the logs in Heroku show more information about the error?